# Defining the material conditional in Prolog

Tags: prolog, logic

I have been trying to acclimate to Prolog and Horn clauses, but the transition from formal logic still feels awkward and forced. I understand there are advantages to having everything in a standard form, but:

What is the **best** way to define the material conditional operator `-->` in Prolog, where `A --> B` succeeds when either `A = true` and `B = true` OR `B = false`? That is, an `if->then` statement that doesn't `fail` when `if` is `false` without an `else`.

[image: truth table]

Also, what exactly *are* the non-obvious advantages of Horn clauses?

Comment: Please pretend that's a conditional arrow.=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the best way to define the material conditional operator --> in Prolog

When `A` and `B` are just variables to be bound to the atoms `true` and `false`, this is easy:

```
cond(false, _).
cond(_, true).
```

But in general, there is no best way because Prolog doesn't offer proper negation, only [negation as failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_as_failure), which is non-monotonic. The closest you can come with actual propositions `A` and `B` is often

```
(\+ A ; B)
```

which tries to prove `A`, then goes on to `B` if `A` *cannot be proven* (which does not mean that it is false due to the [closed-world assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_world_assumption)).

Negation, however, should be used with care in Prolog.

> Also, what exactly are the non-obvious advantages of Horn clauses?

That they have a straightforward procedural reading. Prolog is a *programming language*, not a theorem prover. It's possible to write programs that have a clear logical meaning, but they're still programs.

To see the difference, consider the classical problem of sorting. If `L` is a list of numbers without duplicates, then

```
sort(L, S) :-
    permutation(L, S),
    sorted(S).
sorted([]).
sorted([_]).
sorted([X,Y|L]) :-
    X < Y,
    sorted([Y|L]).
```

is a logical specification of what it means for `S` to contain the elements of `L` in sorted order. However, it also has a procedural meaning, which is: try all the permutations of `L` until you have one that it sorted. This procedure, in the worst case, runs through all *n*! permutations, even though sorting can be done in O(*n* lg *n*) time, making it a very poor sorting program.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108632/why-do-circular-references-and-recursion-make-my-program-fail).

Comment: Not sure I agree with your theorem prover vs. programming language view. And for sorting, please [look at this program](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6218051/772868)

Comment: But I agree with the rest of your answer!

Comment: Thank you, larsmans, for taking the time to write a thorough and clear answer that anticipated my related concerns.

Comment: @false Can you please elaborate on why you may disagree? Or point me to some reading material?

Comment: @false: your sorting example proves my point exactly; by reordering the clauses, you can largely retain the logical meaning but get a completely different program (largely because you use the metalogical `nonvar`).

Comment: @larsmans: but the when-annotation cannot change the meaning of a program (in contrast to simple `nonvar/1` directly in a program)! And you also need performance-tweaks in theorem provers.

Comment: @QuietThud: Will do, but probably not 2day.